# Why I am unable to write to contract in ethereum wallet?

Tags: truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I clicked on the watch contract and entered address and ABI.

But I can't see any functions to write to contract.
[image]

I compiled and deployed contract by using truffle framework

ABI:

```
    {
  "contract_name": "Crowdsale",
  "abi": [
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "checkGoalReached",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "deadline",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "beneficiary",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "tokenReward",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "name": "balanceOf",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "fundingGoal",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "amountRaised",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "price",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "safeWithdrawal",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "ifSuccessfulSendTo",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "name": "fundingGoalInEthers",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "name": "durationInMinutes",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "name": "etherCostOfEachToken",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "name": "addressOfTokenUsedAsReward",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "payable": true,
      "type": "fallback"
    },
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "beneficiary",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "amountRaised",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "GoalReached",
      "type": "event"
    },
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "backer",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "amount",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "isContribution",
          "type": "bool"
        }
      ],
      "name": "FundTransfer",
      "type": "event"
    }
  ],
  "unlinked_binary": "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",
  "networks": {
    "4": {
      "events": {
        "0xec3f991caf7857d61663fd1bba1739e04abd4781238508cde554bb849d790c85": {
          "anonymous": false,
          "inputs": [
            {
              "indexed": false,
              "name": "beneficiary",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "indexed": false,
              "name": "amountRaised",
              "type": "uint256"
            }
          ],
          "name": "GoalReached",
          "type": "event"
        },
        "0xe842aea7a5f1b01049d752008c53c52890b1a6daf660cf39e8eec506112bbdf6": {
          "anonymous": false,
          "inputs": [
            {
              "indexed": false,
              "name": "backer",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "indexed": false,
              "name": "amount",
              "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
              "indexed": false,
              "name": "isContribution",
              "type": "bool"
            }
          ],
          "name": "FundTransfer",
          "type": "event"
        }
      },
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x06d29ab2e694fe6b00f5429fdb474dfc8c841ebe",
      "updated_at": 1503825329632
    }
  },
  "schema_version": "0.0.5",
  "updated_at": 1503825329632
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I added the full compiled code as ABI, but not the actual ABI.